# How to convert array to Dataframe with spark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark

The lst array builded by pandas:

```
lst = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
```

I want to convert lst to spark Dataframe, the struction like:

```
    0
0   [1, 2, 3]
1   [1, 2, 3]
2   [1, 2, 3]
```

I did:

```
x_train = spark.createDataFrame(lst)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lst).map(lambda x: [x.tolist()]).toDF(["Doc2Vec"]).show()

+---------+
|  Doc2Vec|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[1, 2, 3]|
+---------+
```